# Factory Girl before safe callback

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a very specific use-case. I need to each time before saving a factory instance "deleted_user" to assign it `ID` that is free in the "users" table in order the "restore" to work.

```
class DeletedUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  def restore
   User.create!(attributes) # ID here is included and is important to be. We want a user with the same ID that it was before deleting!
  end
end

FactoryGirl.register :deleted_user do
  # need to plug before save and assign ID that never will be used for user ID.
end
```

And There are different ways to persist a factory instance:

1. `FactoryGirl.create :deleted_user`
2. `FactoryGirl.create_list(:deleted_user)`
3. `FactoryGirl.build(:deleted_user).save`
4. `FactoryGirl.build(:deleted_user).save!`
5. `FactoryGirl.build_list(:deleted_user, 2).map(&:save)`
6. `FactoryGirl.build_list(:deleted_user, 2).map(&:save!)`

As I see Factory Girl doesn't have a before save callback but only `before(:create)` and `on_creation`, but they are triggered only for `1, 2` of the above invocations.

Do you know a way to use custom `before(:save)` callback elegantly?

NOTE: My FactoryGirl is `4.5.0`

Comment: I can't understand " I need to each time before saving a factory instance to assign it ID." Can you maybe give and example, or reason why you want to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can include your logic into `after(:build)` as well, since it's not going to touch the database until you call `.save`.